# Get-запрос из JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как в JS функции вызвать GET-запрос. Я хочу перейти в сервлет по URL. Как например если бы я это сделал через форму:

                        
                        **Submit**

Как мне в JS-функции перейти по на url /searchuser и передать параметры?

Comment: Yura, вы с вопросом так же обозначили тег JAVA, данный вопрос связан с JAVA ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если все данные у вас уже есть в функции `JS` вы можете воспользоваться `window.location.href`

`window.location.href="http://vash_domen.ru/searchuser?params=data"`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. А если данных для формы еще нет в функции JS, как тогда вызвать?

Comment: Вызов будет таким же, просто вам надо уже через JS получать отдельно, из каждых инпутов , информацию и подготовить к отправке через GET.

Answer (score 0):

Для формы я использую такой код:

> window.location.assign('/searchuser?id=1&name=Vasya');

Ниже пример конкатенации строки с синтаксисом **es6**

```
window.location.assign(`${location.origin}/clean-form?appartment=${appartment}&bath=${bathroomCount}&roomCount=${roomCount}`);
```